# PhoneGap & HTML5 Video tag & iOS & Vimeo

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, video

I use below code to show a Vimeo video in my PhoneGap iOS application. Below is the code.

```
    <div id="lesson" data-role="content" data-inline="true">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/61702922" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

But I end up having below error in the runtime.

[image]

But if I attach a Youtube video, it shows correctly

```
    <div id="lesson" data-role="content" data-inline="true">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1"></iframe>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this error ? Why does not it support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old problem on **Vimeo** side.

There's a solution but I can't confirm it works. It will work only on your own video material. The solution was to download or just re-upload them to allow **Vimeo** to again re-process the video material. When video is ready use the embed code generated and they should play correctly.

Partially this is also an iOS problem, because videos will play perfectly on iOS 5 but not on iOS 6.

My project required me to show videos not owned by me, and **Vimeo** policy will not allow me to re upload someone else work.

Comment: There are also few other solutions but they will not work under Phonegap, unless you are willing o create your own plugin.